# Does this liminf characterization hold true?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, limits, limsup-and-liminf

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that
$$0<a:=\liminf_{|t|\to\infty} tf(t) <\infty.$$
I am interested in writing the above relation by using the definition. On by lecture notes, I have written that it corresponds to say that, fixed $\varepsilon>0$, it is
$$ tf(t)\geq(a-\varepsilon) - c_1 \quad\mbox{ for all } t, $$
where $c_1$ denotes a positive constant. Now, I would like to obtain a similar relation but using the "reverse" inequality, I mean, it is true that
$$ tf(t)\leq (a+\varepsilon) +c_2\quad\mbox{ for all } t $$
holds too?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is $\beta$?

Comment: Sorry, there were a mistake. I edited the question, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g(t)=\inf \{x f(x): |x|\ge t\}$. This is an increasing function with value in ${\mathbb R}\cup \{-\infty\}$ and we have $\lim_{t\to\infty} g(t) = a$.
The condition that $0<a<+\infty$ is equivalent to the fact that $0<g(t_0)$ for some $t_0$ and $g$ is bounded from above by some constant $A$. This entails the two conditions which characterize the fact that $a \in (0, \infty)$

- $\exists m > 0,\exists t_0 \in {\mathbb R}, \forall t, |t|\ge t_0 \Rightarrow t f(t)\ge m$
- $\exists A\in{\mathbb R}, \exists t_n,  |t_n|\to \infty, t_n f(t_n)\le A$

Comment: Thank you for the  answer. So, my deduction was wrong? Cuold you write, if possible, the second condition using an epsilon-delta argumrnt?

Comment: The problem is that I don't understand the conditions that you have written above. Try to rewrite them using quantifiers $\exists$ and $\forall$ to see what they really mean.

Comment: I refer to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior#Properties

Comment: The connection with your formulas is not obvious. You don't need $\epsilon$ s and $\delta$ s to characterize that $0<a<\infty$. You could use $\epsilon$s to say for example that there is a sequence $|t_n|\to\infty$ such that $t_n f(t_n)\to a$. Such things are written in the Wikipedia page, but you don't need them here. It is much more important to understand the argument with the function $g(t)$.

Comment: Fine, thank you again. But it is not possible to write your second relation in a "easier way", I mean not using the sequence $t_n$ but something like your first charsacterization?

Comment: In plain english the condition is that there exist arbitrarily large values of $|t|$ for which $t f(t)\le A$ (but this is not true for *all* large values of $t$). The "arbitrarily large" part is usually rendered by using a sequence which absolute value tends to infinity. You could say that the set $\{t: t f(t)\le A\}$ is not bounded, but I'm not sure it is clearer.